# New to ML trying to use SVM and SVR for 1st time some syntax/transposition errors

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, time-series, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to run A SVR on some data I got from yahoo finance. I want to use closing prices of Ethereum to predict next 10-15 days path using a supervised learning method. I have already done autoregressive model (ARIMA) but now I want to try ML techniques like pattern recognition so I start with SVR

I am simply running into a problem that I dont know how to convert my data column into a row so that the SVR works...I thought it would be simple but I am new to coding overall...appreciate your help; see below:

''' building a simple model for using machine learning to do pattern recog on stock prices'''

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as ply
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from sklearn.svm import SVR

df = pd.read_csv("C:\Learning\ETH.csv", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
prices = df['Adj Close']
dates = df.index
dates = dates.values.reshape(1,len(dates))

# run support vector regressions to get next predicted value
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3)
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3)
svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
svr_lin.poly(dates, prices)
svr_lin.rbf(dates, prices)
```

When I run this I get following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/.../Machine
>   Learning/MachLearningStockPrediction.py", line 19, in 
>       svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py",
>   line 149, in fit
>       X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')   File
>   "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 583, in check_X_y
>       check_consistent_length(X, y)   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 204, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 1085]

Length of both prices and dates is same 1085 characters

Please help

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
dates = dates.values.reshape(1,len(dates))
```

`dates` will be converted to a row vector which have 1 rows and 1085 columns. In scikit-learn, the required data for X (data features) is `[n_samples, n_features]`. So here, scikit thinks that your data have only 1 sample with 1085 features.

But then your `prices` is of shape [1085, ] which according to scikit should have shape [n_samples, ]. So here number of samples are taken as 1085. And hence the error.

You should do this to correct the error:

```
dates = dates.values.reshape(len(dates), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, but when I implement the change and re-run then the program doesn't seem to stop...I've left it running for over an hour and I get no progress or confirmation that process is finished.

Comment: @user10156750 Thats a problem of your linear svm `svr_lin`. It is not able to converge on the data. only `svr_poly` or `svr_rbf`.